# How to update a django formset?

Tags: python, django, formset

I am new to Django and web development. I am using a formset to save the data into the database. The creation part works fine, but I am facing issues when I try to update the existing data in the database using formsets.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**models:**

```
from django.db import models

class GradingSchemeName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

class GradingScheme(models.Model):
    scheme_name = models.ForeignKey(to=GradingSchemeName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    score_range_begin = models.SmallIntegerField()
    score_range_end = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('scheme_name', 'grade',)
```

**forms:**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, inlineformset_factory

GradeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=GradingSchemeName, model=GradingScheme,
    fields=['scheme_name', 'grade', 'score_range_begin', 'score_range_end'],
    extra=10, max_num=100, can_delete=False
)
```

**views:**

```
# Passing the pre-filled form for rendering. For the sake of illustration, I have hardcoded the `id=1`:
instance = GradingSchemeName.objects.get(id='1')        
context['grade_formset'] = GradeFormSet(instance=instance)

# checking the request data from the post(request) on form submission:
grades_formset = GradeFormSet(request.POST, instance=instance)
```

Note that 3 records were saved in the `GradingScheme` Model during formset creation. When I try to update using the above approach, I see the `grades_formset` has 13 records (3 from the `instance` attribute and 10 from the extra forms). The issue is caused when the `is_valid()` method is executed:

```
if not grades_formset.is_valid():
    messages.error(request, 'Form data is invalid!')
```

The `is_valid()` method is throwing the following errors for each of the 3 records:

- id : This field is required
- "errorlist nonfield": Grading scheme with this Scheme name and Grade already exists.

Not sure, how to fix the above two errors. Any pointers would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I like class-based views, so this would be my possible solution to your problem:

```
from django.db import transaction

class GradeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'Your Template'
    form_class = yourtemplateForm
    model = GradingSchemeName

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            context['formset'] = GradeFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['formset'] = GradeFormSet(instance=self.object)

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.instance = self.object
                formset.save()

        return redirect('your url')
```

Comment: I am not sure, how to use form_class, I will check that out. BTW, I am also using CBVs, however, the view code is too large to show here in StackOverflow. Here is the link to full implementation of the View - https://codeshare.io/GLd0JK. Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Why use scheme_name_id, in the verification to know which method it belongs to?

Comment: with self.object is more than enough to know which object you are trying to modify

Comment: your GradingSchemeNameForm goes in form_class, that way it works better and there would be no need to select the fields in the class

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I am using `scheme_name_id` to identify which `GradingScheme` to update. My template (https://codeshare.io/5Q300W) has two forms. The first form sets the `scheme_name_id`, based on this selection I am populating the values into the second form. The second form is `GradeFormSet`.

Comment: I'm not good at crispy, but the UpdateView receives a single object that you want to modify, so the scheme_name_id seems unnecessary to me, and you are returning many unnecessary contexts because according to the name you have set, you are returning 3 forms, I don't think it is necessary that much

Comment: I think so the issue with using the `self.object` is that we will have to know the primary key in advance. I am trying to achieve the same thing by taking the user input from the first form which sets the `scheme_name_id`. You are right, I am returning three different forms from the context. (1) The first form lists all the `GradingSchemeNames`, and the user makes a selection. (2) The second form allows the user update the GradingSchemeName (selected in the first form). (3) The third form is the formset, which I use to update the entries in the `GradingScheme` :)

Comment: To use the generic update view you need to know the id, because I imagine that in your urls.py file you request the id, to know which object it is going to modify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226938/discussion-between-swaroop-and-cosmos-multi).